# how to use YiiShop extension?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I downloaded YiiShop extension from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiishop/)

Then I followed the instruction:

1.Make a folder in my webapp named modules, then extracted the extension there

2.Do some configuration in webapp/protected/config/main.php

```
'modules' => array(
    ...
    'shop' => array('debug' => 'true'),
    ...
),
```

3.I tried to run it as instructed, webapp/shop/install, but it turns error:

> Alias "shop.ShopModule" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be a permission error..
What operating system you are using?
If linux then try this command in terminal -

> **sudo chmod 777 -R /path_to_root_dir/project_name**
>
> warning : do not use this command in your file system!

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. I already did sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/ but still prompting the same message

Comment: This has to be a permission issue.
go to your modules directory through terminal and then type **ll**. 
this will show you your shop directory permission status.
It should be drwxrwxrwx (rwx - read write execute)

Comment: Ok, here's the result:

joen@joenmarz:/var/www/html/nimalogos/modules$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxrwx  3 joen joen 4096 Agu 25 11:02 ./
drwxrwxrwx 10 joen joen 4096 Agu 25 11:02 ../
drwxrwxrwx 10 joen joen 4096 Mar 15  2011 shop/

Comment: where is your protected directory??
modules should be in your protected directory.
**/var/www/project_name/protected/modules/shop**

Comment: My Bad.. It's outside the protected directory..
I've moved it inside and now It's working. Thanks sprytechies!